# Does Amazon cloud infrastructure or any other cloud owners provides free service to education user, such as student or college instructor?

Tags: java, cloud, parallel-processing, hadoop, cloud-hosting

Does Amazon cloud infrastructure or any other cloud owners provides free service to education users, such as student or college instructor?

Comment: http://aws.amazon.com/education/

Comment: if you have an own server infrastructure, you could also try Eucalyptus which provides the same interface as the amazon cloud infrastructure. http://open.eucalyptus.com/

Comment: Also yahoo, at least some time ago had a hadoop cluster for educational research projects, but now I can't find any links.

Comment: Yahoo don't have a hadoop cluster anymore, they are using bing as their searchengine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://aws.amazon.com/education/